# C# Unity Reading data from JSON into an Object Array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read from a JSON file a series of items into an Object array.
Unfortunately it comes back as null.

Very similar to this issue [Unity C# JsonUtility is not serializing a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787091/unity-c-sharp-jsonutility-is-not-serializing-a-list/64167086#64167086)

So in my particular situation I have the class for the item:

```
[Serializable]
public class StateData
{
    public string name;
    public string location;
    public string gameText;
}
```

The class of the collection of items:

```
[Serializable]
public class StateDataCollection
{
    public List<StateData> stateDatas = new List<StateData>();
}
```

And the class where this is invoked:

```
public class JSONReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string Path = @"S:\repos\myProject\Assets\gameText\";

    void Start()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText(Path + "StateData.json");
        StateDataCollection stateDataCollection = new StateDataCollection();
        stateDataCollection = JsonUtility.FromJson<StateDataCollection>(json);
    }
}
```

Finally the json

```
{
"StateData":[
{
"name": "name", 
"location":"location",
"gameText" : "gameText"},
{
"name": "name", 
"location":"location",
"gameText" : "gameText"},
{
"name": "name", 
"location":"location",
"gameText" : "gameText"
}]
}
```

The object comes back as null.
The file is reading OK.

Any ideas where this is failing?
TY!

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking a few things first:

- Check if the file actually exists. Just use a small `Debug.Log(File.Exists(path))`.
- Try another path -> something save like: [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html). On Windows this will give you something like: *%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages<productname>\LocalState*. This ensures you being able to read/write from/to files.
- Fill the `List` with actual data so you can differentiate between a saved list and the default list.

Edit 1:
I just replicated your Code and made some adjustments to it. It's not perfect but it definately worked for me.

**StateData:**

```cs
using System;

[Serializable]
public struct StateData
{
    public string m_Name;
    public string m_Location;
    public string m_GameText;

    public StateData(string name, string location, string gameText)
    {
        m_Name = name;
        m_Location = location;
        m_GameText = gameText;
    }
}
```

**StateDataCollection:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[Serializable]
public class StateDataCollection
{
    public List<StateData> m_StateData;

    public StateDataCollection() => m_StateData = new List<StateData>();
}
```

**JSONReader:**

```cs
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class JSONReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string FILENAME = "StateData.json";

    private string m_path;
    public string FilePath {
        get => m_path;
        set => m_path = value;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        FilePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, FILENAME);
        Debug.Log(FilePath);// delete me

        StateDataCollection stateDataCollection = new StateDataCollection();
        stateDataCollection.m_StateData.Add(new StateData("Peter", "X", "123"));
        stateDataCollection.m_StateData.Add(new StateData("Annie", "Y", "42"));
        stateDataCollection.m_StateData.Add(new StateData("TheGuyFromTheSupermarket", "Supermarket", "666"));


        SaveStateDataCollectionToPath(FilePath, stateDataCollection);

        LoadStateDataCollectionFromPath(FilePath);
    }

    private void SaveStateDataCollectionToPath(string path, StateDataCollection stateDataCollection)
    {
        // ToDo: some checks on path and stateDataCollection
        string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(stateDataCollection, true);// prettyPrint active

        File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    private void LoadStateDataCollectionFromPath(string path)
    {
        if(File.Exists(path)) {
            Debug.Log($"File exists at: {path}");// delete me

            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            StateDataCollection stateDataCollection = JsonUtility.FromJson<StateDataCollection>(json);

            // delete me
            Debug.Log($"StateDataCollection count: { stateDataCollection.m_StateData.Count}");
            int i = 1;
            stateDataCollection.m_StateData.ForEach(o => {
                Debug.Log(
                    $"Item Nr.: {i}\n" +
                    $"Name: {o.m_Name}\n" +
                    $"Location: {o.m_Location}\n" +
                    $"GameText: {o.m_GameText}\n\n");
                ++i;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I also added a few `Debug.Log()`s for testing.
Usage:
Run it once with `SaveStateDataCollectionToPath(FilePath, stateDataCollection);`  active and once without it. The **Console** should display 3 items.
Edit 2:
I think your issue might have been naming-convention violation. `File` requires `using System.IO;`, which beside `File` also contains `Path`. Unfortunately you also named your `const string` "Path".

Comment: Hey ge.go, thanks a lot for the reply. You helped me find out what what wrong. I used the output file as a basis to build my JSON text and then it worked. Apparently there was something wrong with the formatting but the rest I left unchanged. All the commas, bracers, parenthesis, etc were in place. Only the indentation was different which does not seem to be a cause for error but it works. TY forthe help!